# Vaadin: How to test generatedCells with JUnit

Tags: java, junit, vaadin

In Vaadin as you may know overrided generateCell method is only called when Table needs to build its visible content. So When I write a JUnit Test for this class i couldnt trigger the generateCell method and test it. How can I test this any ideas? Or do I have to use a GUI test tool forthis (which I dont want to because it has quite expensive license)

```
public class AttributeColumnGenerator implements Table.ColumnGenerator {    
@Override
public Object generateCell(Table source, Object itemId, Object columnId) {
    //lots of code here to be tested
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding of the question, I don't think you need to have a GUI test tool here.

There's my idea for simple testing :

1. Create an instance AttributeColumnGenerator.
2. Create an table.
3. Add an Item to the table
4. call `generateCell` with an columnId and itemId.
5. Do the appropriate assert on the Component returned by the method.

Here's a snippet of  my idea

First my `ColumnGenerator` who only create a Label with the value of the cell.

```
public class AttributeColumnGenerator implements Table.ColumnGenerator {

public Object generateCell(Table source, Object itemId, Object columnId) {

    String textToDisplay  = (String)source.getItem(itemId).getItemProperty(columnId).getValue();
    return new Label(textToDisplay);
}
```

}

And the test method

```
    @Test
    public void attributeColumnGenratortest()
    {

        AttributeColumnGenerator columnGenerator = new AttributeColumnGenerator();

        Table table = new Table();
        String columnId = "test";
        table.addContainerProperty(columnId, String.class, "");

        String itemId = "item1";
        Item item = table.addItem(itemId);
        item.getItemProperty(columnId).setValue("Value of item1");


        Label generateObject = (Label)columnGenerator.generateCell(table, itemId, columnId);

        // Assert any properties of the returned Component.
        // In this snippet, I only printOut the boolean comparaison.
        System.out.println( "Value of item 1".equals(generateObject.getValue()));
    }
```

Maybe it's not the best solution, but it's works.

Hope it's help!

Regards.

Comment: thank you, the thing is i create my object types in the cell with a long logic, and i process the table data for this.When it is naturally called, it is called for all the items and properties automatically. if I call manually, i am able to test it for only that specific item right?

Comment: @Spring yes you are testing on an specifing item. You have the table as parameter of the generateCell method, so you can acces to any item. I think with two nested foreach you can test any item with any properties. ex : for(Item item : table.getItemsId){ for(Object propertyId :table.getContainerPropertyIds()){}}

Answer (score 1):

The above approach is enough to test a column generator in isolation. However, this falls short when your column generator has a different behavior each time it is called, or when you need to test the interactions of generated components among themselves.
One way to solve this is to override specific methods of Table to fake an attach.

Here is how (tested using Vaadin 7.1.13) :

```
package com.table;

import com.vaadin.data.util.BeanItemContainer;
import com.vaadin.ui.Table;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

/**
 * @author bernard paulus
 * @since 10/07/2014
 */
public class ColumnGeneratorTest {
    @Test
    public void testColumnGenerator() {
        BeanItemContainer<Bean> container = new BeanItemContainer<Bean>(Bean.class);
        container.addBean(new Bean());
        // fake the attach method
        Table testTable = new Table(null, container) {

            private boolean isTableAttached;

            @Override
            public void attach() {
                isTableAttached = true;
                refreshRenderedCells();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isAttached() {
                return isTableAttached;
            }
        };

        CountingNullGenerator generator = new CountingNullGenerator();
        testTable.addGeneratedColumn(Bean.VALUE, generator);

        // call our fake attach
        testTable.attach();

        Assert.assertEquals(1, generator.getNumberOfCalls()); // check side-effect of generation
    }

    public static class CountingNullGenerator implements Table.ColumnGenerator {
        private int nCalls= 0;

        @Override
        public Object generateCell(Table source, Object itemId, Object columnId) {
            nCalls++;
            return null;
        }

        public int getNumberOfCalls() {
            return nCalls;
        }
    }

    public static class Bean {
        public static final String VALUE = "value";
        private String value;

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```